# how to upgrade gcc to c++11 in ubuntu?

Tags: gcc

how to upgrade gcc to c++11 in ubuntu? shall I face any problem after upgrading my present gcc? 
I am trying to run this code.
`

```
int main()
{
  using namespace std;

int n[5];

//cout << " please enter a character : ";
//cin >> x;
for(int m:n)
cout << m <<" ";
}
```

this is my warning.

> 1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>   1.cpp:15:12: warning: range-based ‘for’ loops only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
>     for(int m:n)
>               ^

Comment: @Kulfy I am using g++ 1.cpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a flag and compile it using

```
g++ -std=c++11 1.cpp
```

#### Explanation:

> -std=
>       Determine the language standard.   This option is currently only
>              supported when compiling C or C++.
>
> c++11 
>    c++0x
>       The 2011 ISO C++ standard plus amendments.  The name c++0x is
>                  deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You compile it with `g++ -std=c++11` or `g++ -std=gnu++11` to tell the compiler that you want that standard. This is shown in the error message you have.

Comment: that does not work. this also gives error.

Comment: Which error does it give?

Comment: actually i have to use g++ instead of gcc. it works. thanks

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade g++ to 11, try the following commands (with `sudo` permission):

```
add-apt-repository --yes ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
apt -qq install g++-11
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-11 10
```